# Cannot Find Symbol: new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

AuthResult is RED. Please help me. Cannot import too. Its says cannot find symbole. Is their any problme ? I am trying lot , but nothing find to fix it.

When clicking ALT+ENTER it does not show import anything

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.rafiq.quickchat;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp, btnResetPassword;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnResetPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        btnResetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //create user
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2`enter code here`.5.2+'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you had added the Gradle dependency in firebase authentication

com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0

worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved This by changing version of the Dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

That is firebase's deprecated way.

1. Follow [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/?authuser=7)
2. Once that is done then follow [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62904335/1087223)
3. Uninstall the app manually and reinstall. You can see New Token in Run Tab.