# Firebase InstanceId: binding to the service failed: Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

App successfully lanches but get this error message in debugging. FirebaseInstanceId: binding to the service failed

App Build Gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true // enable mun

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Android manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".FilterPage"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".filterdashboard" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 6):

I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In my manifest file and got rid of **Firebase InstanceId: binding to the service failed**. Hope it will help.

Comment: this one is strange though. The "binding to service failed" didn't occur me earlier and appeared suddenly after say a few days even though the same functionality I had tested without this permission also. any thoughts on this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded the newest version of `google-service.json` (can be done via Firebase Settings). In my case there was a new entry added to `oauth_client`. After syncing with the file system and rebuilding my app the warning does not seem to appear anymore.

*EDIT 20-02-2020*: After testing this a bit more it unfortunately doesn't seem to help in the end. In my case the error message only for sure occur when starting the app the first time after an uninstall of the app - in most other cases it does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use an actual device. Per my observation, you'll get this kind of error when you use an emulator even though you've already downloaded all the required libraries related to Google Services. I was also able to see other errors from FirebaseInstanceId.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, login to Google Play on emulator (API: R) is fixed the problem. I think it's about Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

Add service tag inside application tag

```
<application>

....

   <activity

         ....

   </activity>

   <service
       android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
       android:exported="false">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
       </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Then add a new kotlin file - MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        System.out.println("NEW_TOKEN :::::::::::::::::::::::::: "+s);
    }

}
```

**Uninstall the App manually and reinstall. This will work.**